# html, url, pass credentials, relative path

Tags: html, credentials

I want to logout from HTTP basic Authentication at request (before browser is closed), so reading on net, the only way is to pass some wrong credentials to server. It work but when I tried with relative path is disaster :)

I use

```
<a href="logout@index.htm" >Logout</a>
```

But the url is

```
http://10.10.0.71/logout@index.htm
```

instead of

```
http://logout@10.10.0.71/index.htm
```

How can I solve this?

Comment: Maybe you can do it with JavaScript; `onclick="window.href = \"http://logout@10.10.0.71/index.htm\"; return false;"`

Comment: @Mooseman -> it's a embedded device :)

Comment: @ Allendar -> I know, works, but the problem is the IP is dynamic, I don't know the host IP, was just the one assigned now by my home router

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Generate the full URL with JS and link to it:

```
<script>
function logoutLink(str) {
  document.getElementById("logoutlink").src="http://logout@"+window.location.host+"/index.htm";
}
</script>
<a id="logoutlink" href="#">Logout</a>
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/9XSYq/ (Doesn't work very well in a fiddle because of their iframe.)

Comment: I don't know the IP! It's dynamic :) But I may try to find with alert(document.URL);

Comment: Thanks very much for you effort. I solve it similar window.open('http://logout@'+window.location.host,'_self');

Comment: Good! By the way, use a ` around code in comments. It will look like `this`.

Comment: Wouldn't you set the `href` property instead of the `src` in your example?